Simulation of SDEs using Karhunen Loeve expansion
A very common and easy way to simulate the solution of a SDE is to use the Euler-Maruyama method. At each time step the only random part comes from the realization of the increment of the Brownian.
It seems to me that simulating SDEs is almost never done using Karhunen Loeve expansion. If no one does it, I guess it’s not a good idea. But why?
Thanks for shedding some light!

I have no idea why this has 3 close votes, when no one seems to be able to answer it…

For KL, you need the orthogonality. Simple as that.
If one uses sampling to simulate a stochastic process governed by an SDE (like the Euler-Maruyama you mentioned), one does not need to find such an orthogonal basis in the function space you are interested in.
However, for KL expansion, one needs this orthogonal basis with a sufficiently decaying spectrum (such that using a truncated expansion is good for applications). Some of the most common bases include Fourier and wavelets. If one works with other kernels (covariance between the states at two time points), then in applications, an SVD needs to be performed. With this in mind, related to research intersecting PDE and data (uncertainty quantification or UQ), KL expansion is usually used to model random fields. Note that in UQ, people normally use something called "polynomial chaos expansion," which is exactly KL for Gaussian processes but extends to other prescribed covariance matrices.
An example: see Nelsen, Nicholas H., and Andrew M. Stuart. "The random feature model for input-output maps between banach spaces." SIAM Journal on Scientific Computing 43.5 (2021): A3212-A3243. equation (4.1) has the KL expansion with the Fourier basis, and the coefficients drawn from a given distribution, and eventually it is usually as the exponents of an exponential as the "random" permeability of a porous medium flow.
